# mysql query find date less then another date

Tags: php, mysql, date

im trying to retrieve a set of id's that are due to expire within the next 7 days, and for the life of me cant get my query to work

```
   $target_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days'));
   $sql = "SELECT subscriptions.`id` FROM subscriptions WHERE date($target_date) <= expires AND cust_id =$_SESSION[uid]";
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you storing the dates as timestamps or unix timestamps, I'm asking because I saw this here: `strtotime('+7 days')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine:

```
$target_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days'));
```

As it structures the date in the same way as MySQL `[YYYY-MM-DD]`

I've switched your query around and applied the `DATE()` function to the 'expires' field and not your `$target_date` as it doesn't need to. Your expires field might be in `[YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS]` format, which might be why it's not working:

```
$sql = "
SELECT subscriptions.id 
FROM subscriptions 
WHERE DATE(expires) >= '$target_date' 
AND cust_id = '$_SESSION[uid]'";
```

Echo out the `$sql` query to find out if its executing it properly and Use the `or die(mysql_error());` to tell you where it's failing.

Use SQL escaping too (Either PDO or mysqli) as has been outlined in another answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks to all who replied, this sorted my problem, also thanks to tadman, will look inti sql escaping

Answer (score 1):

If you create a date in a roughly MySQL compatible format, it should work without having to use the `DATE` function, just compare it as if it were a string.

Your code is in dire need of some proper [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) that would fix this problem and likely a worryingly large number of others in your application.

The query running in PDO or `mysqli` would look roughly like:

```
$target_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days'));
$sql = "SELECT subscriptions.`id` FROM subscriptions WHERE ?<=expires AND cust_id=?";
```

You can then call the appropriate `bind_param` method to link in the right values to those placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with MySQL:

```
SELECT subscriptions.`id` FROM subscriptions WHERE date_add(curdate(),interval 7 day) <= expires AND cust_id =$_SESSION[uid]
```